# How to say "become smaller/lower" in one word in mathematical context?

Tags: calculus, arithmetic

We can say e.g. "You can see $2^x$ outgrowing $x^2$ as x increases in Fig. 6.18.".

How can we express the opposite?

The corresponding example: "You can see $x^2$ ... $2^x$ as x increases". What is a good single word for the gap?

Comment: There’s not a good word for it. Just like there’s no common single-word opposite to “exceed.”

Comment: I agree with @SteveKass.  You might say, "falling behind."

Comment: "is dominated by"? Not a single word, certainly.

Comment: "Becomes progressively smaller than"?

Comment: @SteveKass: I suspected that.

Comment: What's wrong with using two or three words if they get the point across? Also, words are sometimes clearer than formulas, e.g., $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{2^x} = 0.$$

Answer (score 5):

"Outgrowing" is probably best interpreted as "the difference between $2^x$ and $x^2$ grows larger as $x$ increases". If you represent this difference as a formula $2^x-x^2=d$, then the converse, given by the formula $x^2-2^x=-d$ would be "the difference between $x^2$ and $2^x$ decreases as $x$ increases; i.e. $2^x-x^2>x^2-2^x$ for some $x$, and all $y>x$.

Answer (score 4):

How about just "decreases"?

Maybe what you really want to say here is that the increases or decreases are exponential. The difference between, say, $2^3$ and $3^2$ is famously small, but the difference between $2^G$ and $G^2$, where $G$ is a googolplex, are mind-boggling, at least for puny human minds.